# why aren't the images switching in carousel js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a carousel but the images aren't switching although the id is correct, what am I doing wrong,
I am sure that the images are in the right directory
here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var images = new Array('./image1.png', './image2.png', './image3.png');
        ind = 0;
        function next() {
            if(ind < images.length - 1) {
                ind++;
                document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[id];
            }
        }

        function previous() {
            if(ind > 0) {
                ind--;
                document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[id];
            }
        }
    </script>
    <img src="screenshot .png" id="myimg" style="height: 300; width: 300;"/>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="previous" onclick='if(ind > 0) {
            ind--;
            document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[id];
        }'/>
        <input type="button" value="next" onclick='if(ind < images.length - 1) {
            ind++;
            document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[id];
        }'/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[id] here use ind not id like this document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[ind]

Comment: What is the purpose of these functions - if you are not calling them anywhere, and instead try to do the whole thing "inline" in the event handler attributes?

Comment: onclick='if(ind > 0) {
            ind--;
            document.getElementById("myimg").src=images[id];
        } why are you using this when you already create function use function instead of this like onclick="previous()" and onclick='nexr()'

Comment: @Nisha sorry I fixed the ind variable and I did put previous() and next(), but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
const urls = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/123/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/121/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/165/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/75/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/198/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/56/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/87/400/200",
];

const images = urls.map((url) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  return image;
});

let ind = 0;

const updateImage = () =>
  (document.getElementById("myimg").src = (images[ind % images.length]).src);
const next = () => ((ind = ++ind % images.length), updateImage());
const previous = () =>
  ind > 0 ?
  ((ind = (ind + images.length - 1) % images.length), updateImage()) :
  null;
```

```html
<img src="image1.jpg" id="myimg" style="height: 300; width: 300;" />
<form>
  <input type="button" value="previous" onclick='previous()' />
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick='next()' />

</form>
```

Comment: check your images path also I hope it will help you